# Word used to describe a feeling felt by two people at the same time

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is the word used to describe  the feeling where you feel something about someone and apparently the person feels the same...for example...you feel that something bad is going to happen to your friend...apparently yoir friend is feeling the same too.

Or you feel that a friend is sick and it turns out to be true when no ome has told you

Comment: [Synchronicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronicity), perhaps?

Comment: Are you referring to actually feeling the same feeling as the title implies? The same headache, heartbreak, etc...? Or are you referring to the proverbial knot in the stomach, a sense of foreboding that the other person is not ok?

Comment: When thinking the same, you an your friend are on the same page (or on the same wavelength).  But, these idioms don't refer to [telepathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telepathy)

Comment: Shared premonition?

Comment: If the feeling you both have is an upset stomach then perhaps the term you want is "epidemic".  (Seriously, "contagion" might fit.)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on context, **"a hivemind"** may fit.

> "Hivemind (slang) is when two or more people come to the same thought at the same time because of the same circumstances but do not know each other beforehand."
>   [Urban Dictionary](http://pt.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hivemind)

In this particular case the persons involved don't know each other.

Originally, "hive mind" refers to "collective consciousness" as observed with social insects such as ants, termites and bees.

Answer (score 0):

sympathetic, or sympathy - but it also has other common idiomatic meanings that might confuse this classic meaning.

E.g.

- Sympathetic dread
- Sympathetic worry
- Sympathetic pain

Sympathetical may help preserve this classic meaning:

I felt her pain sympathetically.

Dictionary:

** *sympathy* noun, plural sympathies. 1. harmony of or agreement in feeling, as between persons or on the part of one person with respect to another. 2. ... the fact or power of sharing the feelings of another, especially in sorrow or trouble; fellow feeling, compassion, or commiseration.**

Comment: Sympathy related to feeling sorry for someone; *empathy* relates to feeling someone else's emotions. However. I don't think empathy would fit.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I think your recognition of sympathy is very constrained, especially given my warning of a classical meaning.